# Insert Or Update Multiple Model in One Method In Laravel Controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions

**Insert Or Update Multiple Model in One Method In Laravel Controller**

In My controller When I create or update multiple model within on method, I face Some Problem.
If any error in any model or query those model are inserted/update whose are in first.
I want to All model data create/update if there aren't any error, if any errors all insert/update will be fused.

**My Controllers Method**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->authorize('loans.create');
    $this->validate($request, [
        'loan_id'  => 'required|numeric',
        'received_by'  => 'required|string|max:100',
        'received_amount'  => 'required|numeric',
        'deposit'  => 'nullable|numeric',
        'deposit_1'  => 'numeric|nullable',
        'installments'  => 'required|numeric',
        'date'  => 'required|date',
        'total_amount'  => 'required|numeric',
      ]);
    
    
    $loan = new Loan();
    $loan->loan_id = $request->loan_id;
    $loan->received_by = $request->received_by;
    $loan->received_amount = $request->received_amount;
    $loan->deposit = $request->deposit;
    $loan->deposit_1 = $request->deposit_1;
    $loan->installments = $request->installments;
    $loan->date = $request->date;
    $loan->Txn = Str::random(10);
    $loan->total_amount = $request->total_amount;
    $loan->somity_id = auth()->user()->mst_somity_id;
    $loan->is_active = 1;
    $created_user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $loan->save();

    $AssignLoan = AssignLoan::find($request->loan_id);
    $AssignLoan->deposit += $request->deposit;
    $AssignLoan->deposit_1 += $request->deposit_1;
    $AssignLoan->paid_amount += $request->received_amount;
    $AssignLoan->remaining_amount =  $AssignLoan->total_amount - $request->received_amount;
    $AssignLoan->save();
        
    // TransactionReport 
    $TransactionReport = new TransactionReport();
    $TransactionReport->transaction_type = 'loan_received';
    $TransactionReport->customer_id  = $loan['assignloan']['customer_id'];
    $TransactionReport->transaction_description = 'loan received with deposit';
    $TransactionReport->transaction_method = 'cash';
    $TransactionReport->transaction_amount =  $request->total_amount;
    $TransactionReport->transaction_date = $request->date;
    $TransactionReport->transaction_time = date('H:i:s');
    $TransactionReport->transaction_by = $request->received_by;
    $TransactionReport->somity_id = auth()->user()->mst_somity_id;
    $TransactionReport->created_user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $TransactionReport->is_loan_diposite = $loan->id;
    $TransactionReport->Txn =  $loan->Txn;
    $TransactionReport->save();

    //sms info
    $AdminSeetings = AdminSeetings::where('somity_id', auth()->user()->mst_somity_id)->first();
    if($AdminSeetings->automatic_sms == 1){
        $SmsPackageAssignToSomity = SmsPackageAssignToSomity::where('somity_id', auth()->user()->mst_somity_id)->first();
        // $SmsPackage = SmsPackage::find($SmsPackageAssignToSomity->sms_package_id);
        if($SmsPackageAssignToSomity->remaining_sms > 0){
            // $Remaining_sms = $SmsPackage->remaining_sms;
            $customer_number = $AssignLoan['customer']['customer_phone']; 
            $loan_id = $AssignLoan->loan_number;
            $loan_amount =  $request->received_amount;
            $remaining_amount =  $AssignLoan->remaining_amount;
            $message = "Your loan No: ". $loan_id . ". received amount: ".  $loan_amount ." Tk. Remaining Balance: ". $remaining_amount ." Tk.";
            //  dd($message);
            $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->remaining_sms = $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->remaining_sms - 1;
            $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->use_sms = $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->use_sms + 1;

            $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->save();
            $url =   "https://bulksms.aloitltd.com/services/send.php?key=".env('API_KEY')."&number=" . $customer_number . "&message=". $message . "&option=".env('OPTION')."&type=".env('TYPE')."&prioritize=".env('PRIORITIZE');
            return Redirect::to($url);
        } else {
            $notification = array(
                        'message' => 'Loan Added Successfully and SMS LIMIT EXCEED',
                        'alert-type' => 'success'
                );
                return redirect()->route('loan.index')->with($notification);    
        }    
    } else {
        $notification = array(
                'message' => 'Loan Added Successfully',
                'alert-type' => 'success'
            );
        return redirect()->route('loan.index')->with($notification);    
        // return Redirect::to($url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why all the wierd and unnecessary indentation? Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Then you need to do all these updates inside a TRANSACTION

Comment: [Its documented in the manual](https://laravel.io/articles/using-database-transactions-to-write-safer-laravel-code)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion about indentation.
and I was already try use Transaction out site of all code, but return redirect blank page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally Work With This type**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->authorize('loans.create');

    $this->validate($request, [
        'loan_id'  => 'required|numeric',
        'received_by'  => 'required|string|max:100',
        'received_amount'  => 'required|numeric',
        'deposit'  => 'nullable|numeric',
        'deposit_1'  => 'numeric|nullable',
        'installments'  => 'required|numeric',
        'date'  => 'required|date',
        'total_amount'  => 'required|numeric',
      ]);

      try {
        
        DB::beginTransaction();
    $loan = new Loan();
    $loan->loan_id = $request->loan_id;
    $loan->received_by = $request->received_by;
    $loan->received_amount = $request->received_amount;
    $loan->deposit = $request->deposit;
    $loan->deposit_1 = $request->deposit_1;
    $loan->installments = $request->installments;
    $loan->date = $request->date;
    $loan->Txn = Str::random(10);
    $loan->total_amount = $request->total_amount;
    $loan->somity_id = auth()->user()->mst_somity_id;
    $loan->is_active = 1;
    $created_user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $loan->save();
        $AssignLoan = AssignLoan::find($request->loan_id);
        $AssignLoan->deposit += $request->deposit;
        $AssignLoan->deposit_1 += $request->deposit_1;
        $AssignLoan->paid_amount += $request->received_amount;
        $AssignLoan->remaining_amount =  $AssignLoan->total_amount - $request->received_amount;
        $AssignLoan->update();            
            // TransactionReport 
            $TransactionReport = new TransactionReport();
            $TransactionReport->transaction_type = 'loan_received';
            $TransactionReport->customer_id  = $loan['assignloan']['customer_id'];
            $TransactionReport->transaction_description = 'loan received with deposit';
            $TransactionReport->transaction_method = 'cash';
            $TransactionReport->transaction_amount =  $request->total_amount;
            $TransactionReport->transaction_date = $request->date;
            $TransactionReport->transaction_time = date('H:i:s');
            $TransactionReport->transaction_by = $request->received_by;
            $TransactionReport->somity_id = auth()->user()->mst_somity_id;
            $TransactionReport->created_user_id = auth()->user()->id;
            $TransactionReport->is_loan_diposite = $loan->id;
            $TransactionReport->Txn =  $loan->Txn;
            $TransactionReport->save();
            DB::commit();
            $success = true;
      

    
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
            DB::rollBack();
             throw $e
            $success = false;
    }
       
    if($success){
          //sms info
          $AdminSeetings = AdminSeetings::where('somity_id', auth()->user()->mst_somity_id)->first();
          if($AdminSeetings->automatic_sms == 1){
           $SmsPackageAssignToSomity = SmsPackageAssignToSomity::where('somity_id', auth()->user()->mst_somity_id)->first();
           // $SmsPackage = SmsPackage::find($SmsPackageAssignToSomity->sms_package_id);
               if($SmsPackageAssignToSomity->remaining_sms > 0){
                   // $Remaining_sms = $SmsPackage->remaining_sms;
                   $customer_number = $AssignLoan['customer']['customer_phone']; 
                   $loan_id = $AssignLoan->loan_number;
                   $loan_amount =  $request->received_amount;
                   $remaining_amount =  $AssignLoan->remaining_amount;
                   $message = "Your loan No: ". $loan_id . ". received amount: ".  $loan_amount ." Tk. Remaining Balance: ". $remaining_amount ." Tk.";
                   //  dd($message);
                   $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->remaining_sms = $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->remaining_sms - 1;
                   $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->use_sms = $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->use_sms + 1;

                   $SmsPackageAssignToSomity->save();
                  
                   $url =   "https://bulksms.aloitltd.com/services/send.php?key=".env('API_KEY')."&number=" . $customer_number . "&message=". $message . "&option=".env('OPTION')."&type=".env('TYPE')."&prioritize=".env('PRIORITIZE');
                   return Redirect::to($url);
               } else{
                   $notification = array(
                       'message' => 'Loan Added Successfully and SMS LIMIT EXCEED',
                       'alert-type' => 'success'
                   );
                   return redirect()->route('loan.index')->with($notification);    
               }
           
       } else {
           $notification = array(
               'message' => 'Loan Added Successfully',
               'alert-type' => 'success'
           );
           return redirect()->route('loan.index')->with($notification);    
           // return Redirect::to($url);
       }
    } else{
        $notification = array(
            'message' => 'Loan Not Added',
            'alert-type' => 'error'
        );
        return redirect()->route('loan.index')->with($notification);    
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggest. I was trying your suggested way but not working because in my code there are many condition, but I got another solution from other that's try
        {
          DB::beginTransaction();
          insert/update all your models here
          DB::commit();
           $sussecc = true;
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
                DB::rollBack();
               throw $e
               $sussecc = false;
        }

Answer (score 0):

try `beginTransaction` according to official [documentation of laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#manually-using-transactions)

```
{
        try
        {
          DB::beginTransaction();
          insert/update all your models here
          DB::commit();
        }
        catch (\Exception $e)
        {
                DB::rollBack();
        }

}
```

Comment: try this but nothing do anything

Comment: This solution also work in normal codding, but my code is more complex with some conditional exception